# How to filter out all emails that came from a mailing list in Gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Is there a way to filter out all emails that came from a mailing list within Gmail or Google Apps Script using a search query. I know you can filter out a specific email address using `list:info@example.com`. But I want a catch-all type of query or even a query to catch-all from a specific domain such as `list:@example.com`. However, this does not work. Any ideas? Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried **from:*@example.com**?

Comment: I only want the emails from my companies domain that were sent from a mailing list: address not just any email that matches the company domain. I hope that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to avoid replying to emails that come from a mailing list address by using the `getRawContent()` method and then searching that string for "Mailing-list:". So far the script is working like a charm.

```
function autoReply() {
      var interval = 5;    // if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
      var date = new Date();
      var day = date.getDay();
      var hour = date.getHours();
      var noReply = ["email1@example.com",
                     "email2@example.com"];

      var replyMessage = "Hello!\n\nYou have reached me during non-business hours. I will respond by 9 AM next business day.\n\nIf you have any Compass.com related questions, check out Compass Academy! Learn about Compass' tools and get your questions answered at academy.compass.com.\n\nBest,\n\nShamir Wehbe";
      var noReplyId = [];

      if ([6,0].indexOf(day) > -1 || (hour < 9) || (hour >= 17)) {
        var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
        var threads = GmailApp.search('from:@example.com is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
        var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("autoReplied");
        var repliedThreads = GmailApp.search('label:autoReplied newer_than:4d');

        // loop through emails from the last 4 days that have already been replied to
        for (var i = 0; i < repliedThreads.length; i++) {  
          var repliedThreadsId = repliedThreads[i].getMessages()[0].getId();
          noReplyId.push(repliedThreadsId);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {     
          var message = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
          var messagesFrom = message.getFrom();
          var email = messagesFrom.substring(messagesFrom.lastIndexOf("<") + 1, messagesFrom.lastIndexOf(">"));
          var threadsId = message.getId();
          var rawMessage = message.getRawContent();
          var searchForList = rawMessage.search("Mailing-list:");
          var searchForUnsubscribe = rawMessage.search("Unsubscribe now");

             // if the message is unread, not on the no reply list, hasn't already been replied to, doesn't come from a mailing list, and not a marketing email then auto reply
             if (message.isUnread() && noReply.indexOf(email) == -1 && noReplyId.indexOf(threadsId) == -1 && searchForList === -1 && searchForUnsubscribe === -1){
                message.reply(replyMessage);
                threads[i].addLabel(label);
          }     
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will trash all messages from all inbox thread that are not in the list.

```
function emailFilter() {
  var list=['a@company.com','b@company.com','c@company.com','d@company.com','e@company.com'];
  var threads=GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  var token=null;
  for(var i=0;i<threads.length;i++) {
    if(threads[i].getMessageCount()) {
      var messages=threads[i].getMessages();
      for(var j=0;j<messages.length;j++) {
        if(list.indexOf(messages[j].getFrom()==-1)) {
          messages[j].moveToTrash();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I haven't tested it because I keep my inbox empty all of the time.  You might want to replace 'moveToTrash()' to 'star()' for testing

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I just want to be able to filter out emails that originated from a google mailing list. Essentially I already have an auto-reply script I put together and want to add in logic that will have it not respond to any emails that came in from a mailing list address.

Comment: Oh I thought that you just wanted to receive emails from the list.

Answer (score 0):

What I could understand from your question and your comments, you need to filter the emails in a user's inbox that he has received, which don't only contain a certain label, but also a certain domain. If I understood well this code can help you:

```
function checkLabels() {
  // Get the threads from the label you want
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Label Test List");
  var threadArr = label.getThreads();
  // Init variable for later use
  var emailDomain = '';
  // Iterate over all the threads
  for (var i = 0; i < threadArr.length; i++) {
    // for each message in a thread, do something
    threadArr[i].getMessages().forEach(function(message){
      // Let's get the domains from the the users the messages were from 
      // example: list:@example.com -> Result: example.com
      emailDomain = message.getFrom().split('<').pop().split('>')[0].split('@')[1];
      // if emailDomain is equal to example.com, then do something
      if(emailDomain === 'example.com'){
        Logger.log(message.getFrom());
      }
    });
  } 
}
```

Using the [Class GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) I got a certain label with the [***.getUserLabels()***](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getuserlabels) method and iterate through the threads thanks to the [***.getInboxThreads***](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getinboxthreads) method. With a second loop and the [***.getMessages()***](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread.html#getmessages) you can get all the messages in a thread and for knowing the one who sent them, just use the [***.getFrom()***](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message.html#getfrom) method.

### Docs

For more info check:

- [Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail).
- [Class GmailMessage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message.html).
- [Class GmailThread](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread.html#getmessages).